# Is there any provision in keycloak always redirect to the dashboard after login and re-login?

Tags: single-sign-on, wildfly-8, keycloak

Is there any provision in keycloak always redirect  to  dashboard after  login and re-login?

Comment: Isn't it covered by redirect_uri parameter?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, it is covered by redirect_uri parameter but how it's possible to override it with dashboard url in every login and re-login(After session expired)?

Comment: In keycloak js adapter there is method login(). You can pass object with redirectUri property. keycloak.login({ redirectUri: "http://google.com" })